# AngularJS ng-if hidden elements with ng-select event not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a hidden `select` input which is hidden by `ng-if`. In the hidden `select`, I have added a `ng-change` tag, which in turn calls a function to display an `img` which is also hidden by `ng-if`.

1. `hiddenNinja` is initially hidden.
2. Upon an external function, `hiddenNinja` displays it's elements (e.g. `select` input).
3. When value of `select` is changed, `hiddenTommy` is not displayed.

However, if `hiddenNinja` is initially shown, then only would `hiddenTommy` be displayed.

Codes for the example below.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NinjaController"> // Controller is here
    <div ng-if="hiddenNinja"> // ng-if is here
        <select ng-change="validateFilled()" ng-model="data"> // ng-change & ng-model
            <option selected>First</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in items" >{{ item }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

// Image shown below.
// On the actual code, image is a footer on a different php file,
// Which is also why I use $rootScope in this example.
// For this question, I'll include this image in this partial view.
<img src='randomSource' ng-if='hiddenTommy' />
```

Angular:

```
app.controller('NinjaController',['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.data = "First";
    $scope.items = ['Sight', 'Smell', 'Taste', 'Sight', 'Touch'];

    $scope.validateFilled = function() {
        if ($scope.data != "First") {
            $rootScope.hiddenTommy = true;
        }
    };
}]);
```

I have sourced online for answers to no avail.
I would appreciate any help provided.

Thank you all for reviewing this piece of code.

Comment: `($scope.data != "First")` is returning false `$rootScope.hiddenTommy = true;` never gets triggered

Comment: @PavittarGill Oh! Okay, thank you so much for your insight. I have discovered that, `$scope.data` is always `First`. Found out using `alert`. But thanks for your suggestion, it helped a bunch.

Comment: Have You tried using **ng-show** for img tag

Comment: Yes, I have tried. Apparently, as @PavittarGill mentioned, the statement `($scope.data != "First")` is always returning false, due to the fact that `$scope.data` is always undefined regardless of what option I select. However, when `hiddenNinja` is initially displayed, `$scope.data` returns a value every time I change my option. I'm trying to work my way around this, but of course, if there is any more suggestions, I would very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `$scope.data` is always 'First' in your controller is, that ngIf directive has its own scope and therefore when you select a value `data`only changes in that scope, not in the scope you expect it to. Use `$scope.data = { select: 'First' }` in your `NinjaController` and then `ng-model="data.select"`. So there is no reason to create a factory for that. Read more about scopes here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

PS: You should use `ng-options` instead of placing `ng-repeat` on `option` to add the items to the select box, it is a good practice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This would help me improve myself. I'll heed your advice and read up more on scopes.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time, but good news, I managed to solve my own problem.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="NinjaController"> // Controller is here
    <div ng-if="hiddenNinja"> // ng-if is here
        <select ng-change="validateFilled(data)" ng-model="data"> // <-- Changed here
            <option selected>First</option>
            <option ng-repeat="item in items" >{{ item }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<img src='randomSource' ng-if='hiddenTommy' />
```

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('NinjaController',['$scope', '$rootScope', 'SystemFactory',
    function($scope, $rootScope, SystemFactory) {

    $scope.items = ['Sight', 'Smell', 'Taste', 'Sight', 'Touch'];

    $scope.validateFilled = function(data) {
        SystemFactory.storeOption(data);
        if (SystemFactory.checkIfNotEmpty() == true) {
            $rootScope.hiddenTommy = true;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Angular Factory:

```
app.factory('SystemFactory', [function() {
    var SystemFactory = {};

    // Variable to store selected option
    var selectedOption = "";

    SystemFactory.storeOption = function(temp) {
        selectedOption = temp;
    }

    SystemFactory.checkIfNotEmpty = function() {
        if (selectedOption != "") {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return SystemFactory;
}]);
```

Haven't been able to work on this issue until recently. So I'm glad I managed to solve this, I'm posting this solution in case anyone encounters the same issue.